# How to scrape and download the table in HTML page using JSOUP through java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tried this...but rows and columns printing separately...my requirement is download the table from HTML page

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String html = "URL";
      // Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
     System.out.println(doc);
     Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");

     Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
    System.out.println("headers");
     for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());
     }
     System.out.println();

     Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");

     for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
        Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
        System.out.println("row");
        Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
        for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
           System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Is is not clear to me where the problem is. Your code looks okay. Do you get an error? If so, please print the StackTrace. Can you post the original html table and tell us what output you need exactly.

Comment: <html>
 <head></head
 <bod
  http://factfinder/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=PEP_2014_PEPANNRES&amp;src=pt
 </body>
</html>
headers

Comment: when i am executing the above code getting following message as shown in above... but what i want is to download the table from html page to some dot extension file.

Comment: What do you mean by download? You want to write a file from your java process with the table data? If so, use the file system methods of java or some wrapper around it like apache commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html.

Comment: my requirement is store the table data in html page into some file(.txt/pdf...) please help me

Comment: So your problem is not with html and not with Jsoup. It is about how to write files from Java. I would suggest reading about that topic. For example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the tutorial that [luksch wrote in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331254/how-to-scrape-and-download-the-table-in-html-page-using-jsoup-through-java#comment56406034_34331254), a solution could be:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow34331254;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

/**
 * Reply to stackoverflow 34331254 question.
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_THEAD.html";
        String fileName = "table.csv";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        System.out.println(doc);
        Element tableElement = doc.select("table").first();

        Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElement.select("thead tr th");
        System.out.println("headers");
        for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());
            writer.append(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());

            if(i != tableHeaderEles.size() -1){             
                writer.append(',');
            }
        }
        writer.append('\n');
        System.out.println();

        Elements tableRowElements = tableElement.select(":not(thead) tr");

        for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
            Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
            System.out.println("row");
            Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
                writer.append(rowItems.get(j).text());

                if(j != rowItems.size() -1){
                    writer.append(',');
                }
            }
            writer.append('\n');
        }

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This will create a `csv` file that will contain the first table (including headers).

The table content is:

```
<table cellpadding="6" rules="GROUPS" frame="BOX">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Weekday</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Manager</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Mon</td>
         <td>09/11</td>
         <td>Kelsey</td>
         <td>639</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Tue</td>
         <td>09/12</td>
         <td>Lindsey</td>
         <td>596</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Wed</td>
         <td>09/13</td>
         <td>Randy</td>
         <td>1135</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Thu</td>
         <td>09/14</td>
         <td>Susan</td>
         <td>1002</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Fri</td>
         <td>09/15</td>
         <td>Randy</td>
         <td>908</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sat</td>
         <td>09/16</td>
         <td>Lindsey</td>
         <td>371</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sun</td>
         <td>09/17</td>
         <td>Susan</td>
         <td>272</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th align="LEFT" colspan="3">Total</th>
         <th>4923</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

The `csv` output will be:

```
Weekday,Date,Manager,Qty
Mon,09/11,Kelsey,639
Tue,09/12,Lindsey,596
Wed,09/13,Randy,1135
Thu,09/14,Susan,1002
Fri,09/15,Randy,908
Sat,09/16,Lindsey,371
Sun,09/17,Susan,272
```

**UPDATE**

[The table that you're talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331254/how-to-scrape-and-download-the-table-in-html-page-using-jsoup-through-java/34381479?noredirect=1#comment56570499_34381479) is loaded from another url: http://factfinder.census.gov/tablerestful/tableServices/renderProductData?renderForMap=f&renderForChart=f&pid=PEP_2014_PEPANNRES&src=pt&log=t&_ts=468903667318

It contains a `productDataTable` property with the table content.

Comment: Hello Davide Pastore ...first of all thank u for your quick response, answer that you are posted working fine but in my case the data that to be in the table loaded dynamically and it doesnt show data while scraping

Comment: @satish do you mean that data is loaded using ajax requests?

Comment: Hello @Davide Pastore.. surely data is not loaded using ajax requests..and  we can't see the table in page source

Comment: Can you add the link that contains the table?

Comment: http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=PEP_2014_PEPANNRES&src=pt

Comment: Hello @Davide Pastore.. if u can't get the table then please close and reopen the link. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello @Davide Pastore... thank u bro.. its working fine now.

Comment: Hello @Davide Pastore... can u share your mail id. I have a small doubt regarding url in above case..

Comment: Or else just ping me at sateesh.karuturi9@gmail.com  Thank you in Advance

Comment: @Sateesh Karuturi, you can just write here.